# How to detect touch end of image view when touches moving

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, touches

I have an image view. i detected touch in image view like this

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   int viewTag=[touch view].tag;

   if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
   {
      //My code
   }
}
```

and touches moved on image view. whenever my touch moved out off the image view in that particular time i need one alert view. how to detect that touch over from the image view in touches moving?...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and adding it to a larger super-view of the image-view you want to detect on. That way even if the touch starts outside and moves into and out of your image-view you can follow the movement of the touch in your gesture handler.

It's pretty easy, make a method called `handlePan:` for example, create the gesture recognizer using your handler method, add it to the appropriate super-view. Now whenever the gesture is active and the touch moves your handler method will get called and you can check to see if it is inside your image view.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this method...

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   int viewTag=[touch view].tag;

   if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
   {
  //My code
   }
   else
   {
      //show the alertView here
   }
}
```

and to check that the initial click was on the imageView you have to set a flag in the touchesBegan method... and check it accordingly in the touchesMoved method

Comment: touchesEnded is working in with in the image only, but he want to touchesMoved Detection.

Comment: changed the answer.. I think this is what he wants

Comment: thanks for your replay. But it is not working. In if condition i placed NSLog(@"Touch Moved"); and in else condition NSLog(@"Touch End");. When i touch imageview and touches moving on the imageview in this time "Touch Moved" log is called and touches moved out of the imageview in that time also "Touch Moved" is called

Answer (score -1):

You may add a transparent `UIButton` of the same size on top of the `UIImageView`and track `UIControlEventTouchDragOutside`

`[button addTarget:self action:@selector(draggedOutside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];`